# how do I get values into a list with enumerate in python?

Tags: python, list, object, tensorflow, enumerate

I have the following code:

```
# coding: utf-8

# # Object Detection Demo
# Welcome to the object detection inference walkthrough!  This notebook will walk you step by step through the process of using a pre-trained model to detect objects in an image. Make sure to follow the [installation instructions](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md) before you start.

# # Imports

# In[ ]:


import numpy as np
import os
import six.moves.urllib as urllib
import sys
import tarfile
import tensorflow as tf
import zipfile

from collections import defaultdict
from io import StringIO
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

if tf.__version__ < '1.4.0':
  raise ImportError('Please upgrade your tensorflow installation to v1.4.* or later!')


# ## Env setup

# In[ ]:


# This is needed to display the images.
get_ipython().magic('matplotlib inline')

# This is needed since the notebook is stored in the object_detection folder.
sys.path.append("..")


# ## Object detection imports
# Here are the imports from the object detection module.

# In[ ]:


from utils import label_map_util

from utils import visualization_utils3 as vis_util


# # Model preparation 

# ## Variables
# 
# Any model exported using the `export_inference_graph.py` tool can be loaded here simply by changing `PATH_TO_CKPT` to point to a new .pb file.  
# 
# By default we use an "SSD with Mobilenet" model here. See the [detection model zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md) for a list of other models that can be run out-of-the-box with varying speeds and accuracies.

# In[ ]:


# What model to download.
MODEL_NAME = 'ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2017_11_17'
MODEL_FILE = MODEL_NAME + '.tar.gz'
DOWNLOAD_BASE = 'http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/'

# Path to frozen detection graph. This is the actual model that is used for the object detection.
PATH_TO_CKPT = MODEL_NAME + '/frozen_inference_graph.pb'

# List of the strings that is used to add correct label for each box.
PATH_TO_LABELS = os.path.join('data', 'mscoco_label_map.pbtxt')

NUM_CLASSES = 90


# ## Download Model

# In[ ]:

# =============================================================================
# 
# opener = urllib.request.URLopener()
# opener.retrieve(DOWNLOAD_BASE + MODEL_FILE, MODEL_FILE)
# tar_file = tarfile.open(MODEL_FILE)
# for file in tar_file.getmembers():
#   file_name = os.path.basename(file.name)
#   if 'frozen_inference_graph.pb' in file_name:
#     tar_file.extract(file, os.getcwd())
# =============================================================================


# ## Load a (frozen) Tensorflow model into memory.

# In[ ]:


detection_graph = tf.Graph()
with detection_graph.as_default():
  od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
  with tf.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_CKPT, 'rb') as fid:
    serialized_graph = fid.read()
    od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
    tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')


# ## Loading label map
# Label maps map indices to category names, so that when our convolution network predicts `5`, we know that this corresponds to `airplane`.  Here we use internal utility functions, but anything that returns a dictionary mapping integers to appropriate string labels would be fine

# In[ ]:


label_map = label_map_util.load_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS)
categories = label_map_util.convert_label_map_to_categories(label_map, max_num_classes=NUM_CLASSES, use_display_name=True)
category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index(categories)

def load_image_into_numpy_array(image):
  (im_width, im_height) = image.size
  return np.array(image.getdata()).reshape(
      (im_height, im_width, 3)).astype(np.uint8)



# # Detection    
# In[ ]:


# For the sake of simplicity we will use only 2 images:
# image1.jpg
# image2.jpg
# If you want to test the code with your images, just add path to the images to the TEST_IMAGE_PATHS.
PATH_TO_TEST_IMAGES_DIR = 'test_images'
TEST_IMAGE_PATHS = [ os.path.join(PATH_TO_TEST_IMAGES_DIR, 'image{}.jpg'.format(i)) for i in range(1, 3) ]

# Size, in inches, of the output images.
IMAGE_SIZE = (12, 8)

with detection_graph.as_default():
  with tf.Session(graph=detection_graph) as sess:
    # Definite input and output Tensors for detection_graph
    image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')
    # Each box represents a part of the image where a particular object was detected.
    detection_boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')
    # Each score represent how level of confidence for each of the objects.
    # Score is shown on the result image, together with the class label.
    detection_scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
    detection_classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
    num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')
    for image_path in TEST_IMAGE_PATHS:
      image = Image.open(image_path)
      # the array based representation of the image will be used later in order to prepare the
      # result image with boxes and labels on it.
      image_np = load_image_into_numpy_array(image)
      # Expand dimensions since the model expects images to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
      image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
      # Actual detection.
      (boxes, scores, classes, num) = sess.run(
          [detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections],
          feed_dict={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})


      # Visualization of the results of a detection.
      vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
          image_np,
          np.squeeze(boxes),
          np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
          np.squeeze(scores),
          category_index,
          use_normalized_coordinates=True,
          line_thickness=8)
      plt.figure(figsize=IMAGE_SIZE)
      plt.imshow(image_np)


      print ([category_index.get(value) for index,value in enumerate(classes[0]) if scores[0,index] > 0.5])
```

print ([category_index.get(value) for index,value in enumerate(classes[0]) if scores[0,index] > 0.5])

This effectively prints this out:

```
[{'id': 1, 'name': 'person'}, {'id': 1, 'name': 'person'}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'car'}, {'id': 1, 'name': 'person'}, {'id': 1, 'name': 'person'}, {'id': 1, 'name': 'person'}, {'id': 1, 'name': 'person'}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'car'}, {'id': 1, 'name': 'person'}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'car'}]
```

My question is:
1. How do I get the length of objects.
2. How do I get it to store the values in a new list, with only the name of the item.

This is how I want objects to be assigned (not printed):

```
length = 10

name[0] = 'person'
name[1] = 'person'
name[2] = 'car'
name[3] = 'person'
name[4] = 'person'
name[5] = 'person'
name[6] = 'person'
name[7] = 'car'
name[8] = 'person'
name[9] = 'car'
```

Thanks in advance!

I need to clarify a bit, the print command is only there so I can visualize what I have. I don't mean to just print it to look like in the output, I want that to exist as objects, that I can later retrieve and do computations with.

Comment: can we see the sample input data?

Comment: `len(object)` gives length
The list comprehension only serves to confuse people trying to help you, Rather just show sample input as per @JacobIRR's comment

Comment: I added the entire code for context, thanks.

Comment: None of the code you have just posted helps at all.  In fact it makes it almost impossible to see what you are doing.  The code you had posted was fine, we wanted to see input data (basically the output of `classes`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this using a second list comprehension, or if you post your initial data, there is probably a way to avoid having to create a second list:

```
your_list = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'person'}, {'id': 1, 'name': 'person'}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'car'}, {'id': 1, 'name': 'person'}, {'id': 1, 'name': 'person'}, {'id': 1, 'name': 'person'}, {'id': 1, 'name': 'person'}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'car'}, {'id': 1, 'name': 'person'}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'car'}]


name = [item['name'] for item in your_list]
```

Output:

```
['person', 'person', 'car', 'person', 'person', 'person', 'person', 'car', 'person', 'car']
```

And to get the length just output `len(name)` which outputs `10`

**EDIT**

To clarify based on what you are asking, change this line:

```
print ([category_index.get(value) for index,value in enumerate(classes[0]) if scores[0,index] > 0.5])
```

to:

```
your_list = [category_index.get(value) for index,value in enumerate(classes[0]) if scores[0,index] > 0.5]
```

And then use:

```
name = [item['name'] for item in your_list]
```

To get the list with just the names.

Comment: Thank you! But the thing is that "your_list" is not coded, this is the output, thats what I want to be gathered from the enumeration.

Comment: You said that the code you currently have outputs what I have labeled `your_list`, you can use the second list comprehension to get only the names from your initial output.

Comment: I'm not sure quite how to do that, what you have on "your_list" is printed, but I want that to exist in a list, I don't want to manually put that in, because that value will always change. I have added more context, so you can see where it's derived from.

Comment: The line in your code where you print the list, instead of printing, assign it to a variable, then use the code I have posted.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3 [f-strings](https://cito.github.io/blog/f-strings/) were introduced, which allows you to simplify the printing logic a bit, if you want exactly the same output format you showed in the question:

```
items = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'person'}, {'id': 1, 'name': 'person'}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'car'}, {'id': 1, 'name': 'person'}, {'id': 1, 'name': 'person'}, {'id': 1, 'name': 'person'}, {'id': 1, 'name': 'person'}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'car'}, {'id': 1, 'name': 'person'}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'car'}]

print(f"length = {len(items)}\n")
for i, item in enumerate(items):
    print(f"name[{i}] = {item['name']!r}")
```

Output:

```
length = 10

name[0] = 'person'
name[1] = 'person'
name[2] = 'car'
name[3] = 'person'
name[4] = 'person'
name[5] = 'person'
name[6] = 'person'
name[7] = 'car'
name[8] = 'person'
name[9] = 'car'
```

Comment: Thank you! I need to clarify a bit, the print command is only there so I can visualize what I have. I don't mean to just print it to look like in the output, I want that to exist as objects, that I can later retrieve and do computations with.

Comment: @basviccc Well, that would be good information to include in your question, then! In that case go with what chrisz used in his answer.